# How to create a point in the upper left corner of the pixel in the QGIS function?

Tags: qgis

Using pixel to point in QGIS creates a point in the center of the pixel.

Is there a way to create a point in the upper left corner of the pixel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform them afterwards (with pixel size in half) to move the points.

[image]